# Can we use two source table or more in a page or in page extension in AL BC365?

Tags: dynamics-business-central

I've created a page extension which extends **"item card"** , now what i'm trying to do here is that **i have** a **table** which **i created**, and want to **access fields** of that table **in** this **Page extension**.

Basically the problem is that the **"item card"** page already have **"item"** as its source table, and i also want to access my table's fields in this page extension. Is there a way to do that?

I'm totally new to **Microsoft Business Central 365 AL Development**. So, Please help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to define a local variable for your table in your Page Extension.

Then using the trigger OnAfterGetRecord (also in your Page Extension) you retrieve the record in your custom table corresponding to the current Item.

Something like this (which I haven't tested) provided that the primary key in your custom table is Item No.:

```
trigger OnAfterGetRecord(); 
begin 
    MyTable.Get("Item No.")
end; 

var 
    MyTable: table "My Table";
```